# Read process memory of a process does not return everything

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, readprocessmemory

I am trying to scan memory of a 3rd party application. I have already found out the address; right now is at `0x0643FB78`. The thing is, I can never get up there since `LPMODULEENTRY32->modBaseAddr` is `0x00400000` and `LPMODULEENTRY32->modBaseSize` is merely `0x006FF000`, thus the max address I can scan for this module is `0x00AFF000`.

Does that mean the address I seek does live inside another process/module/thread/something? I am quite confident the process I have does contain the address though. How should I access the memory then? Thank you.

Comment: MODULEENTRY gives you addresses of *code*.  Surely you are more interested in data?  That can appear anywhere, depending on where Windows allocated the heap.  Or the data section, hopefully, since you'll have little hope of getting that address repeatable if it is actually in the heap.  Use VirtualQueryEx() to enumerate the allocations in the address space.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At least in my opinion, if you have an `LPMODULEENTRY` involved, you're probably starting in the wrong direction. I'd walk through the blocks of memory in the target process with `VirtualQueryEx` instead. This will give you a `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` about each block in that process. You can then use `ReadProcessMemory` and scan through the blocks to find what you're looking for.

Here's some old code I wrote to do roughly the same thing, but looking for a string rather than a pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class InIter1, class InIter2, class OutIter>
void find_all(unsigned char *base, InIter1 buf_start, InIter1 buf_end, InIter2 pat_start, InIter2 pat_end, OutIter res) {
    for (InIter1 pos = buf_start;
        buf_end!=(pos=std::search(pos, buf_end, pat_start, pat_end));
        ++pos)
    {
        *res++ = base+(pos-buf_start);
    }
}

template <class outIter>
void find_locs(HANDLE process, std::string const &pattern, outIter output) {

    unsigned char *p = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    for ( p = NULL;
        VirtualQueryEx(process, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info);
        p += info.RegionSize ) 
    {
        std::vector<char> buffer;

        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT && 
            (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)) 
        {
            SIZE_T bytes_read;
            buffer.resize(info.RegionSize);
            ReadProcessMemory(process, p, &buffer[0], info.RegionSize, &bytes_read);
            buffer.resize(bytes_read);
            find_all(p, buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), output);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <process ID> <pattern>", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int pid;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%i", &pid);

    std::string pattern(argv[2]);

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess( 
        PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
        false,
        pid);

    find_locs(process, pattern, 
        std::ostream_iterator<void *>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, this will certainly put me on the right path. Thank you.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin - +1 for the great answer. Two things that I would like to further ask: 1) Once I have read the content of the page into the char vector `std::vector<char> buffer` -- how should I "treat" it ? I mean, does it contain ASCII characters or UTF-8/UTF-16 encoded characters ? In case the memory is holds ASCII characters, how do I convert them to Unicode (I guess it should be UTF-16) ? 2) For what exactly the `std::vector<char>::iterator pos` is used for ? Your help is much appreciated !!

Comment: @GuyAvraham: The data is copied verbatim from the target process, so it's in whatever format the target process used. `pos` is a leftover from some earlier version of the code--it's not used at all.

Answer (score 4):

A process consists of pages of memory which are mapped with certain protections. These pages are encapsulated in modules. Each module has a base and a size. However, ReadProcessMemory abstracts this from you completely. You should be able to read memory regardless of what module it is in.

In this case, the memory is not in the module you are looking at. If you do need to find where it belongs, you can iterate through the modules checking base and size with CreateToolHelp32Snapshot, Module32First and Module32Next.

Post some code and we can help you find out where you've gone wrong. Why are you so sure the address of what you are looking for is the address you state? Addresses are often specified with a base module + offset because of ASLR. How are you getting the target process handle? You need to have certain access rights to use ReadProcessMemory.

Comment: Thanks, this is the insight I was lacking. I accepted Jerry's answer because he's got the code sample though.