# ReadProcessMemory faster

Tags: c++, c, winapi, memory

I'm making an application that will simulate an action using mouse/keyboard (macro) deppending on the value of a variable.

Here I have de scanning code that I made:

```
void ReadMemory(int value){
        DWORD primeiroAddress = 0x000000;
        DWORD finalAddress = 0xFFFFFF;
        DWORD address=0;
        std::ostringstream ss;
        int i=0;
        TListItem *ListIt;
        int valor;
        HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ,0,TargetPID);
        if(!phandle){
                ShowMessage("Não encoutrou o processo");
        }else{
                for(address=primeiroAddress;address<=finalAddress;address+=sizeof(valor)){
                        ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&valor,sizeof(valor),0);
                        if(valor==value){
                                i++;
                                ss << std::hex << address;
                                Form1->Label5->Caption=i;
                                ListIt = Form1->ListView1->Items->Add();
                                ListIt->Caption = AnsiString(ss.str().c_str()).UpperCase();
                                ListIt->SubItems->Add(IntToStr(valor));
                                ss.str(std::string());
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I was wondering what I could make to make the scanning faster

Comment: Side note, there is a resource leak as the handle is never closed, you need to `CloseHandle(phandle);` if `OpenProcess()` succeeded.

Comment: You should be checking the return value from `ReadProcessMemory()`.  I imagine that for many of the addresses in the range `0` - `0xffffff` you'll get an error return (in particular, the addresses in the range `0` - `0xfff` should always fail, I think).

Comment: First, read in big chunks, and second only read addresses that contain real data. See [example code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10373209/179910) from a previous answer.

Answer (score 6):

You're reading one `int` at a time. Instead call `ReadProcessMemory` once, reading the 16MB in one swoop, then scan the memory in your own process. It'll be a lot faster.

Comment: wwwhatt, explain me better, i got really interested in that, i need to scan from 000000 to FFFFFF 16.777.215 bytes i think that is the 16MB you said right, but how i put that to a space for my program to scan? like into a variable

Comment: Ahhh, `char *buffer = new char[0x1000000]` ?

Comment: Hmm and then i would make the reading from the string how?
if(value==buffer[i]) ?

Comment: How would i make the reading of the ReadProcessMemory if i use the char? please can you send me a simple code doing the reading and if possible a statement checking if the value is equal to the var value

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,buffer,0x1000000,0)`

Comment: after ReadProcessMemory, starting from 000000 the content of buffer is only '\0' which is the end of string, what can i do?

Comment: LPBYTE *point;
LPBYTE buffer = new BYTE[finalAddress-primeiroAddress];
ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)primeiroAddress,buffer,finalAddress-primeiroAddress,0);
point=&buffer+address;
valor=(int)*point;
if(valor==value){

thats what i managed to do, now it is getting values from the memory address again but it give me an error of Access violation at address 00401B0C, what i do?

Comment: C is obviously not your cup of tea. Have you considered switching to a managed language like C#, and doing a little inter-op instead?