# Scanning through process memory

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory

I want to write a process scanner to detect malicious code and I need to scan every section of a PE executable loaded in memory. I've been wondering how to do it and it seems to me that there are two viable solutions:

- ReadProcessMemory

Pros: easy to use
Cons: must read and copy memory to a buffer, can't read the whole process memory because of the limited buffer, searching is also difficult because of the little "window" of memory copied to the buffer at a time

- Inject a DLL into the process' memory

Pros: Able to access directly process memory, no copy required
Cons: "injecting" is frowned upon by several security programs and it's a rather tricky method, plus I need to copy also the data the program needs to work with

My question is: is there another method to accomplish a complete memory scan of another process' memory (given that I have the privileges to do that) ?
If not: how should I deal with the need to scan the whole memory if I need to read one little "window" at a time?

Comment: see how it works something that can help in [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Unless you really *need* to execute code in the target process, `ReadProcessMemory` is clearly the right way to do the job. I posted a demo in a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10373209/179910).

Comment: That's a nice answer, put it as an answer and I'll accept it