# VirtualQueryEx returns MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION having region size -1

Tags: c, winapi, memory, readprocessmemory, virus-scanning

I am writing a memory scanner. I am first using a call to `VirtualQueryEx` to get memory base address and region size into a `struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` and then using a call to `ReadProcessMemory` to read the memory.

The problem i am facing is that `VirtualQueryEx` fills the `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.Region Size` with `-1`.

Why does it do that?
What is the meaning of this `-1`?

Comment: Does `VirtualQueryEx` returns success (a non-zero value)?

Comment: .. and if it does not what does GetLastError() return?

Comment: Are your process and the target both 32 bit, or both 64 bit? And please do show some code and prove to use that you are calling the functions correctly, and checking errors correctly.

Comment: `while((bytes_to_read=VirtualQueryEx(hProcess,addr,&meminfo,sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)))!=0)

 {

  if (meminfo.State & MEM_FREE)//checking if memory page is free or used
  {
   addr += meminfo.RegionSize;//here it is adding -1 so it is not going to next page
   continue;
  }

`
I am doing this on a virtualbox 64 bit win 7 virtual machine

Comment: For what it's worth, a working scanner that might provide a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10373209/179910. (I've tested this on a number of different OSes, so if it doesn't work for you, chances are pretty good it's a problem with your environment).