# Find new addresses based on programs memory

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, hex

I am basically trying to write something that will read a processes memory for specific pointers.

I want it to read the addresses and return the value for those addresses, then I want it to add a list of offsets to those values and return the new addresses to me (just the way the particular program works). I got all of the pointers and offsets using Cheat Engine, the Value at the addresses change constantly and it is draining to have to get the new value each time it changes.

For example: If I have a pointer address of 21F64D70 I would want it to read that; lets say the value at that address at that particular time is 01A9A320, I would want it to then add a list of offsets to 01A9A320. So I would want it to do say 01A9A320 + 00000432 and 01A9A320 + 00000434 and return 01A9A752 and 01A9A754 to me.

Any tips on how to write something along these lines? I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention C#, you're presumably running Windows. In that case, you can use [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx) to read data from a process. Once you've read it, the list of offsets and such is a matter of simple math.

In [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373209/179910) I gave a general demonstration of using `ReadProcessMemory` to scan through a process' memory to find a specified string. If you have a known starting point, some of that becomes superfluous, but the part that calls `ReadProcessMemory` itself remains valid.

Comment: Here is a [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670373/Csharp-Read-Write-another-Process-Memory) that goes in to more depth on how to to the P/Invoke calls to `ReadProcessMemory`