# How to find address of a variable which declared in local scope?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2017

this topic about **finding** variables of another process using c++.

The problem is - i don't know how to find the place in virtual memory where local variables are allocated. I'm already succeed with finding variables which:

1. declared in global scope
2. any static variables

Using WINAPI function [GetModuleInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation) and [MODULEINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/ns-psapi-_moduleinfo) i'm getting info where executable of chosen process starts, and where it ends (`EntryPoint` is start and `SizeOfImage` - end). So, with that, using `for` loop i'm finding any variable of another program like in milliseconds.

But the problem is - it's working only for global and static variables. I tested all the stuff with my test program, which have only 2 variables(1 global, 1 inside `main` function) and `cout's` for it. And here is example how it's looks.

According to `EntryPoint` and `SizeOfImage` i'm getting picture how big memory allocation of my test program. For instance memory allocation starts in `16 000 000` and ends in `17 500 000` - it is(as i understand) scope in which all stuff of my test.exe is allocated, so i'm scan it with `for` loop looking for variable, and i successfully find it, any global variable, and it takes less then second.

But i can't find in that scope of test.exe my local variable, i manually change scan start position from `16 000 000` to 0, and i'm finding my local var in virtual memory at position like 3 000 000 .

Why that variable placed in that place, and not in scope of .exe where all variables of program should be.

I've spent enormous amount of time to find the answer, but in google mostly about simple stuff like reading/writing memory, rarely examples how to find global variables, but nothing about local or heap variables. Please, i hope there is some experienced human which know how to find allocation of local variables.

Comment: Variables in local scope only exist for on stack frame for the duration of the call of the function that contains them.  They can be in different places on the stack depending on the call path to the function.

Comment: @RichardCritten How then i can get to know where this "stack frame" placed in virtual memory?

Comment: I don't think you can.  For a particular function it only exists for the duration of the function call; may not exist at all in optimised builds; will be at different address if the function is called on a different call path and will be used for a different function when the function of interest is not active.

Comment: This is a much harder question than it would seem to be. But it is possible - after all I can attach a debugger to my process and ask it what each thread is doing and what locals are available for each thread. However, this is _hard_ -you basically need to write significant parts of a debugger. And in some cases (like when the local variable has been optimised out or I don't have the correct PDB) its pretty much impossible. Whats the actual reason you want to do this?

Comment: Local variables can't be presumed to "exist" at all. A good optimizing compiler can and will take a lot of liberties with these if the structure of the code permits it. Unused variables get removed. Frequently used variables get stored in registers, not in system memory, and so on. If you *need* an address then you should probably allocate it with `new`.

Comment: You haven’t found an answer because there isn’t one. Local variables haven’t been implemented like that since the late 1950s or so, when the benefits of reentrant functions were discovered.

Comment: You can't. Variables are a compile-time concept. There is no representation of that in object code (although object code may contain artifacts that can be attributed to variable declarations).

Comment: Local variables may only exist as registers.  In most platforms, you can't get the address of a register.  Although, if you do take the address of a local variable, the compiler can't locate it in a register.

Comment: @MikeVine i just get interested in that, trying to understand how all that bot/cheat programs work, how they get access to other processes and all variables in it. Like guy which made CheatEngine alone, his soft can find that local variables immediately. So i just tried try myself, at least in something small like this.
P.S. guys which before commented here that that impossible. Rly, it's not just possible, it's already existing as free software for decades...

Comment: Presuming that CheatEngine really is finding _local_ variables (as opposed to other kinds), maybe it's using some kind of real-time statistical analysis of the target program as it runs, or maybe hardcoded with special knowledge of certain games/engines, or if working against a program written in any sort of interpreted language then maybe using extra inform provided by the workings of the language. If it's doing this against programs written in C++, then that's gotta be going well beyond the C++ standard and into murky implementation details.

Comment: @Cou: You are confusing *"variable"* with *"storage"*. Variables are strictly a programming language construct. Variables that refer to objects with identity (i.e. glvalues) are treated by the compiler, as if they have a memory address. If the compiler determines, that no one ever uses the address, it can instruct the optimizer to never store the value in memory. While you can view memory, there simply is no way to find variables. Presumably, CheatEngine doesn't find function local objects either. A game will usually store a player's HP in a place, that's valid throughout the game duration.

Comment: I suppose there is no answer might be for this topic. Pity.

Comment: There *is* an answer to this question: You cannot. This is a variation of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). *"Variables"* and *"storage"* are different concepts. The question is asking about the former, but is probably interested in finding the latter. Since this question already has active answers, it's probably best for you to ask a new question.

Comment: @IInspectable Qustion like "how CheatEngine finding local/heap variables"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to write/test a memory scanner, and probably for a game maybe. In such cases usually the variables in question are not local variables, and instead are **global or variables on the heap**. I would suggest you to make sure it's the local variable that you are looking for.

Another thing is, you may need to **scan the additional memory** using Virtual memory APIs like Virtualxxx functions. Since I believe not all areas are within the PE's range of addresses. Thus scanning PE file in memory will only give you an expanded image.

Another tip is, in case you are not able to find the value you are scanning, it may so happen that value is kept **encoded/encrypted** in memory by that process. Try a "has changed" kinda approach to identify those areas then.

Happy hunting!

Comment: I would like your comment, but i'm a bum which dont have even 15 points. 

1. It's not for a game, it's for self Studying, i'm just curious how other people did that, and trying to do the same.
2. Program i'm using for tests it's not a game(yet), it's my own program which just printing two kind of variables if their values are changed. 
3. Why would anybody create in game global variables for HP for all monsters, what it the point of it. When i'm launch the game, and siting in main menu, map in which monsters are spawn dont even start to load. Maybe user won't even load the map.

Comment: "Virtual memory APIs" it's probably stuff i'm looking for

Comment: Don't worry we all have been there :). Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372872/read-process-memory-of-a-process-does-not-return-everything/10373209#10373209 , it may help you to go in right direction.

Comment: Hey, this "VirtualQuery" looks exactly what i was seeking for, after exploring this will report here.

Comment: What a nasty people sitting on this forum, half "commented" that it's not possible or i "you acutally can't find local variables" and alot dislikes with no objective reason.

I finally succeed. Simply using VirtualQueryEx function i'm getting info about all memory process using, so i'm finding my desired local variable address in quarter  of second or so, just like CheatEngine. But there is even more, with such tool i can find variables on the heap to. Therefore - conclusion, this forum is not a best place for asking or discussing.

Comment: @CountDracula Look, most of the folks here are super intelligent, and super busy. Thus not a lot of attention is given to questions which shows inadequate knowledge or research. Don't take me wrong, but probably you seem a little new at how OS/Memory works. Your definition/understanding  of "local" variable is slightly inaccurate. Instead what everybody said is correct, local variables could not be generally located by scanning. I would suggest you come back and read your own question after an year and you will realize what we mean. So don't be upset, stick around this is a great forum.

Comment: Probably you right. Now i looked at this topic and see that would be better dont write that huge page as a question, instead just ask "how can i find out about all memory process actually using".

Answer (score 1):

Local Variables "exist" for the duration of the call of the function that contains them so that being said, there is no way to tell in what Stack Frame it is placed. You can read more about Local and Global variables in this [Article](https://www.codesdope.com/cpp-scope-of-variables/)

Comment: Local variables exist, until the compiler is done emitting object code. Whether a variable's **storage** exists during a function call, during part of a function call, or not at all is at the liberty of any given compiler's optimizer. An optimizer is free to repurpose the storage of a local variable to hold the value of another variable, if it can determine, that their logical lifetimes do not overlap.